# Is it possible to have a batch file to comple and run a program?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is it possible to make batch file for compiling the code in MS cobol 2.20 ?

For example I have a small program and then I want to compile this in using the command

```
COBOL FILENAME;
```

But I want the command to be shorter so that no need for me to type the word COBOL.

This is what I want.

For example like this:

```
                 C filename; //this will compile now the program
```

And to run the program I want also to use one letter.

```
                  r filename; //this will run my program
```

Comment: Can you elaborate and what the commands you execute to get the program compiled without a batch file? And accept some answers on your previous questions.

Comment: @rene,Okay everytime i compile my cobol program i used this command...."COBOL MYPROGRAM;" and to run it i used this "COBOL MYPROGRAM"...that's it...and now i want to make a .BAT so that i can make it shorter to compile my program.let take this an example for compiling instead of typing the word COBOL i just want to use "C MYPROGRAM;"then this will compile now my cobol program.

Comment: @rene,can you help me on this please how to make a .BAT file so that i can shorter my command in compiling and running the program.Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the difference between compiling and running. I see no difference in the examples (only a ; in your comment)

Comment: hi sorry for the late reply,when compiling it should have this ";" when running the program you omit the ";".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open your favourite texteditor (for example notepad) and type:

```
COBOL %1;
```

and now save this as **c.cmd** in the same folder as where your COBOL source file is.

You can now type

> c yourcobolfile.src

to compile your program

for running your program:
open your favourite texteditor (for example notepad) and type:

```
RUN %1
```

and now save this as **r.cmd** in the same folder as where your COBOL source file is.

You can now type

> r yourcobolfile

to run your program

Comment: hi @rene,when running the program is to omit ";"

Comment: @ rene,it works on compiling but in running my program does not work,can you help me please.

Comment: no there is no message it's just like when i am compiling my program

Comment: Did you removed the ; from the r.cmd file?

Comment: Yup i removed it, this the result after doing this R MYFILE Object filename[MYFILE.INT] LISTING filename [NUL.LST]:

Comment: You did do c MYFILE first? Does it work if you type COBOL MYFILE?

Comment: ,sorry my mistakes..if i will run my program i used this RUN MYFILE and then omitting ";".that's how i run my program.so what should i do now to my r.cmd?

Comment: i used this command RUN MYFILE when i am going to run my program..yes i do first the C MYFILE and it's working in compiling my program...

Comment: Hi,it's working now i can now run the program.thank you so much rene...hehehehe..by the way where did you learn that?